# How to convert Korean to text using flutter(dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-to-text

I am currently developing an application that converts Korean to text using flutter.
I've been trying to use the [`speech_to_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) package, but I'm wondering if the only language I can use is English.

Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [speech_to_text's Switching Recognition Language](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text#switching-recognition-language) documentation:

> The speech_to_text plugin uses the default locale for the device for speech recognition by default. However it also supports using any language installed on the device. To find the available languages and select a particular language use these properties.
>
> There's a locales property on the SpeechToText instance that provides
> the list of locales installed on the device as LocaleName instances.
> Then the listen method takes an optional localeId named param which
> would be the localeId property of any of the values returned in
> locales. A call looks like this:
>
> ````
>     var locales = await speech.locales();
>
>     // Some UI or other code to select a locale from the list
>     // resulting in an index, selectedLocale
>
>     var selectedLocale = locales[selectedLocale];
>     speech.listen(
>         onResult: resultListener,
>         localeId: selectedLocale.localeId,
>         ); ```
> ````

If the user has Korean locale installed on their device, you should be able to find it in `locales`. Why don't you place a breakpoint on `var selectedLocale ...` or run `print(locales)`.